# how to test MultiChoiceItems android dialog box

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I build an `AlertDialog` box with

```
  public class ConstantDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    private AlertDialog alertDialog;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final int[] constantProtocol = {0};
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT);

        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.some_message))
                .setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.some_choice, null,
                        new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                                                boolean isChecked) {
                                // some method
                            }
                        })
                .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok_dialog), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    class LoadConfigTask {
                        private ProgressDialog dialog;
                        private Activity activity;

                        public LoadConfigTask(Activity activity) {
                            this.activity = activity;
                            dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT);
                        }

                        public void execute() {
                            try {
                                // some method

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // some method

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // some method
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.cancel_dialog), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // some thing 
                    }
                });
        builder.create();
        alertDialog = builder.show();
        return alertDialog;
    }

    public AlertDialog getAlertDialog(){
        return alertDialog;
    }
```

Then I tried this `espresso` implementation:

```
onView(withText("my first choice")).
                perform(click());
```

and I get

```
NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with text: is my string"
```

How can I fix that ?

Comment: What has that all to do with your dialogbox?

Comment: @greenapps I don't really understand your question. I build a multiitem dialog box and I need to test the some behaviour after having clicked on one of the checkbox

Comment: Where does this onView reside? Why dont you post complete code? Start with the listener code.

Comment: @greenapps this comes from a fragment called from the `MainActivity`. Btw, I have non pb testing the `Ok ` button of the box

Comment: Please post complete reproduceble code.

Comment: @greenapps I put the entire code. You can replace any method by logging or whatever. This fragment is called from MainActivity through usual `FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        ConstantDialogFragment constantDialogFragment = new ConstantDialogFragment();
        constantDialogFragment.show(manager, "fragment_edit_name");`

Comment: Now what does not work on this box if you click a multiple choice item?

Comment: And where does this onView() reside?

Comment: And what do you want to happen with this perform(click())? Where is the connection with your dialogbox? And with one of those items?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117140/discussion-between-newben-and-greenapps).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fetching in the `Android` source code, I found useful methods. So to get control on the items of the `AlertDialog`, I had to do that

```
ListView listView = alertDialog.getListView();
View child = listView.getChildAt(0);
child.performClick();
```